# How do I identify the specific object to which no path can be found in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a number of `<dwarf> cancels <job>: Could not find path` announcements. For example, the job might be "load stone trap".

When I recentre on the dwarf which produced this failure, the dwarf is somewhere distant from the task they are trying to accomplish.

How, in this specific example for a trap, and for similar other pathfinding failures (e.g. collect cobwebs etc), can I find the target location?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming v50 isnt too different from v47, you should have a list of all active and pending jobs listing relevant dwarves, buildings, and status. On this list, you could potentially have "Load stone trap" listed with a "suspended" status.

In version 50, this list should be available at `Labor Menu [y] → Work details tab` according to [this page](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Labor#Managing_labor_and_demand)